# UrlFetchApp.fetch with very long URLs

Tags: url, google-apps-script, url-rewriting, get, google-sheets

New to Google Apps Script, trying to retrieve data from a URL with `UrlFetchApp.fetch` but the URL length is limited to 2kB per call (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

Thus, with a long URL I get the error `Limit Exceeded: URLFetch URL Length.`.

Example:

```
var url = 'http://www.longurlmaker.com/go?id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
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
```

Is there any way I can get around this limit, maybe by using another library to make the GET request?

**EDIT**

Jack Brown's solution works well if I run the function from the script editor. In order to make the functionality accessible as a google-spreadsheets function, I used the following:
[Using the UrlShortener API in a custom Spreadsheet function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429435/using-the-urlshortener-api-in-a-custom-spreadsheet-function)

Comment: Try to check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157226) and [github issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1/issues/8) if it can help you.

Comment: The link you provided "using urlshortener API..." Seems to address the same problem you are facing. Could you expand on what trouble you facing  with when following code given in that link? Also, is this custom function for distribution or private usage?

Comment: The is for private use and will not be distributed. The code from the link uses the REST api of the service and not `UrlShortener` and works also as a function in a spreadsheet.

Comment: I found one way to invoke a function calling `URLShortener` over a menu item, which also works: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/3r3sOazAWCY

Comment: However, I in my 'real' data I have addresses consisting of IPs and API calls, e.g.  `http://127.0.0.1/?something&somethingelse...` I noticed that goo.gl does not shorten these due to security reasons, while with tinyurl.com it works. I'm thus trying to use tinyrul.com with POST from my script...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Url Shortener API to create a short URL and pass it to URLFetchApp like so:

```
function shortenUrl() {
  var Lurl = 'http://www.longurlmaker.com/go?id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
  var url = UrlShortener.Url.insert({
   longUrl: Lurl 
  });
  Logger.log('Shortened URL is "%s".', url.id);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url.id);
  Logger.log(response)
}
```

Make sure you have selected URL shortener API under Resources>Advanced Google Services> URL shortener API v1 (set to on) and also enabled the same in developers console. For more details refer [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/url-shortener)

**EDIT**

Google shortener seems to have some issues with a certain type of URL. This is a more generalized solution. You can select different providers by modifying provider key in the payload below. More details can be found [here](http://www.tiny-url.info/open_api.html)

```
function shortenUrl(Lurl) {
  if(Lurl == undefined){
    var Lurl = 'http://www.longurlmaker.com/go?id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
    }
  var payload = {
    'apikey': 'your API Key', //Create a new Key here http://www.tiny-url.info/request_api_key.html
    'provider' : 'tinyurl_com',
    'format' : "text",
    'url' : Lurl}
  var options = {
    'method':'POST',
    'payload':payload
  }
  var url = "http://tiny-url.info/api/v1/create"
  var response =UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  var turl = response.getContentText()
  Logger.log(turl)
  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(turl)
  Logger.log(response)
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This works well when I run the function from the script editor. But how can I use this function in a google spreadsheet? Question is edited..

Comment: Thanks, tiny URLs are now created, even if I give an IP address. However, in this case, the redirect won't work in the second `UrlFetchApp`.For example, tinyurl.com/lar2hyq works (the above example), but tinyurl.com/kmfyb82 fails... I can get both contents with `curl -L`, but why does UrlFetchApp not work?

Comment: Yep, I can reproduce the error. However, I think the best approach based on your tinyurl is to make a get Request directly to the server at "http://145.136.242.167:8080/v2/specimen/query" with the querySpec parameters. I could, of course, be wrong about the get request. Also more information on what you are trying to achieve might be useful

Comment: The reason I did not make a GET request is that the querySpec was too long `UrlFetchApp`. But I just realised that I can also do a POST request, and send the querySpec as the payload! Thanks for answering my questions, you helped me a lot!

Comment: Looks like a interesting project, all the best!

Comment: Unfortunately on a large enough query url, the shortener will return an error. I recommend doing a POST query, which can carry up to 10mb of payload.

Answer (score 2):

On March 30, 2018, Google deprecated the URL Shortener service that was used in the accepted answer.

I wrote a [script](https://github.com/amitwilson/GoogleAppsScript/blob/master/LinkShortner) to use the Firebase Dynamic Links Short Links API service.

The docs are [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener) if you want to cook your own.