# Can't use ArrayFormula() with custom ImportJSON() function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, custom-function

I use the formula below to pull opening hours for a business whose place_id specified in column B. The formula source is a code.gs sourced from [here](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs) (link is to GitHub)

```
=ImportJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id="&B2&"&fields=opening_hours/weekday_text&language=iw&key=AI*********","/result/opening_hours/weekday_text", "noHeaders")
```

When I try to bind the formula inside of an `ArrayFormula()` and changing `B2` to `B2:B`
​I get the error "**Exception: Limit Exceeded: URLFetch URL Length. (line 146)**",
which in the code refers to `var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);​`
Any way to still array this formula?

Comment: Can you try this:   Create a helper column with 5ish urls without variables in them.  Then change your formula to Arrayformula(ImportJSON(C2:C,"/result/opening_hours/weekday_text", "noHeaders").  Arrayformula sometimes does unexpected things with concatenation.

Comment: You can try to shorten your url via URL Shortener API. Try reading the answer in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43142607/urlfetchapp-fetch-with-very-long-urls/43196448